# Enable links and other functionalities only for admin role

Tags: jsp, security, admin

I'm developing a simple web application which requires authentication. I would like some JSP pages with some links or functionalities hidden to normal users and visible to admin users.
Shall I put a lot of if statements in my JSP pages? Or shall I put a bean that performs this control in my JSP pages?

I don't like these solutions and I hope you can advice me another one.
I'm using Struts2 so I would like respect MVC pattern as more possible.

Answer (score 3):

This needs to be controlled in the view side. You don't need to put `if` statements by *scriptlets*. Just use taglibs to control the flow. For example, JSTL:

```
<c:if test="${user.admin}">
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
</c:if>
```

Here, the `${user}` should just point to some bean representing the logged-in user which has in the above example a `public boolean isAdmin()` getter method. If it returns `true`, then the delete button in the above example will be shown. I don't use Struts2, but as far as I see in its documentation, there's a `<s:if>` tag which does effectively the same.

Comment: ok, but I must put this snippet in each jsp page in which are administrator links. I would like avoid this. Is there any other method? Thanks!

Comment: If it are reuseable page fragments and you want to avoid code duplication, just use `<jsp:include>` or create a custom tag.

Answer (score 2):

You have many options which you can choose.one of them is what @Balus C has mentioned in his post.

Additionally you can show entirely different jsp for user and Admin which will prevent a lot of if else statement
you can configure in struts.xml file like

```
<action name="abcc" class="abc">
    <result name="admin_page">/templates/admin.jsp</result>
    <result name="user_page">/templates/user.jsp</result>
  </action>
```

you can always send result name from your action class based on your logic as what to show.
If you are seriously implementing role based access i must suggest you to user such framework one of them is `Spring security`